# How to rewrite the frameid in a rosbag?

Tags: rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I  recorded a rosbag and tried to visualize it in Rviz. I get the following message `MessageFilter [target=left_hand ]: Discarding message from [unknown_publisher] due to empty frame_id.  This message will only print once.` On doing a rostopic echo, I can see that the frame_id is empty. I ran `rosrun tf view_frames` to generate the pdf.

How do I rewrite the header frame id?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/259459/how-to-rewrite-the-frameid-in-a-rosbag?/) by [Joy16](https://answers.ros.org/users/27343/joy16/) on ROS Answers with karma: 112 on 2017-04-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rosbag has a python API that you can use for reading and creating new bag files; have a look at the [rosbag cookbook](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Cookbook) and the [rosbag API](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag/Code%20API)

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2017-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1